# Asynchronous shell commands

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, asynchronous

I'm trying to use a shell script to start a command. I don't care if/when/how/why it finishes. I want the process to start and run, but I want to be able to get back to my shell immediately...

Comment: Related, see [Difference between nohup, disown and &](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3886) on the Unix and Linux Stack Exchange.

Comment: For those looking for a more in-depth answer that talks about the differences between **`nohup`, `&` and `disown`**, [click here to scroll to the fourth answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37531889/1459669).

Answer (score 145, accepted):

You can just run the script in the background:

```
$ myscript &
```

Note that this is different from putting the `&` inside your script, which probably won't do what you want.

Comment: I knew it was going to be something easy, thanks a ton... Linux just isn't my thing, but I'm trying to get up to speed... Btw, will this work when combined with nohup?

Comment: What is the difference between putting the & on the command line and putting it in the script? I was not aware that they were different.

Comment: @JacobSharf, give it a try and you'll see.  If the `&` is inside the script and you don't have a `wait`, the background command will be killed when the script exits.

Comment: oh. That explains a lot. I was recently noticing some effect that would be caused by that. Googling it actually lead me to this page. Thanks

Comment: If `myscript` modifies the terminal environment, ex. it is a terminal initialization command that is not needed immediately and can be delayed, will it still modify the terminal environment?

Comment: The meaning of running in the background is, The default behavior of the kernel is Synchronous If we want to change it to Asynchronous then we use '&', Which makes the command run in an Asynchronous (parallel) way (that's why it looks to running in the background)

Answer (score 97):

Everyone just forgot `disown`. So here is a summary:

- `&` puts the job in the background.

  - Makes it block on attempting to read input, and
  - Makes the shell not wait for its completion.
- `disown` removes the process from the shell's job control, but it still leaves it connected to the terminal.

  - One of the results is that the shell won't send it a `SIGHUP`(If the shell receives a `SIGHUP`, it also sends a `SIGHUP` to the process, which normally causes the process to terminate).
  - And obviously, it can only be applied to background jobs(because you cannot enter it when a foreground job is running).
- `nohup` disconnects the process from the terminal, redirects its output to `nohup.out` and shields it from `SIGHUP`.

  - The process won't receive any sent `SIGHUP`.
  - Its completely independent from job control and could in principle be used also for foreground jobs(although that's not very useful).
  - Usually used with `&`(as a background job).

Comment: I can't find `disown` on Debian or OS X. I thought it was a program, but I seem to be mistaken. What is it?

Comment: [disown command](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-disown-command-examples-usage-syntax/) and on [OSX](http://ss64.com/osx/disown.html)

Comment: This is the best answer. Most comprehensive.

Comment: Definitely the best answer, don't know why so little ups

Comment: There is also the widely available [`setsid`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/setsid.1.html) to _immediately send the command in background_; the current session can be safely closed too.

Comment: Thanks.
I still have doubt. Is it necessary to call `disown` if the command was run with `nohup` like `nohup my-script.sh > out 2>&1 &`

Comment: @VladGanshin No.

Comment: @jww `disown` is a [shell builtin command](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish/en/man1/bash.1.html#shell%20builtin%20commands)

Answer (score 58):

```
nohup cmd
```

doesn't hangup when you close the terminal. output by default goes to nohup.out

You can combine this with backgrounding,

```
nohup cmd &
```

and get rid of the output,

```
nohup cmd > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

you can also `disown` a command. type `cmd`, `Ctrl-Z`, `bg`, `disown`

Comment: Cool, crazy how everything combines, I think the ordering would get to me at first, but I suppose you could just memorize it ( what you wrote or "nohup cmd & > /dev/null 2>&1" :) )

Comment: I stumbled upon this tonight. I've been fighting with a shell script for 2 days and this suggestion got things working. Thank you mucho!

Comment: Awesome, this is very useful. When running in background mode, you can check the command's output every once in a while using `tail nohup.out`, this will display the last 10 lines of the command output. I use this for rsync backup jobs to see what file it's currently at.

Comment: What if I do this, but want to stop the background process?

Comment: The shell prints a job identifier when you start a job precisely for this purpose. You can see your running jobs at any time with `jobs`.

Comment: Discarding the output is a poor idea. Send it to a file so you can see what it's doing and react to any error messages.

Answer (score 29):

Alternatively, after you got the program running, you can hit Ctrl-Z which stops your program and then type

> bg

which puts your last stopped program in the background. (Useful if your started something without '&' and still want it in the backgroung without restarting it)

Comment: Thanks, thats a cool little trick... Starting to really appreciate some of the shell goodness...

Answer (score 8):

`screen -m -d $command$` starts the command in a detached session. You can use `screen -r` to attach to the started session. It is a wonderful tool, extremely useful also for remote sessions. Read more at `man screen`.

Comment: @LadenkovVladislav I'm 95% certain you can install screen on RedHat.  I have on CentOS.

Comment: On Ubuntu, I wanted to emulate the Windows / batch "start" command. I.e. asynchronously launch a foreground (gui) program, and continue on through a shell script.  This does exactly that.