# Multiple process from one bash script

Tags: bash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Asynchronous shell commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368137/asynchronous-shell-commands)

I have 2 bash scripts, scriptA and scriptB. From within scriptA, scriptB is called.  Is there a way to get scriptA to exit before scriptB? Thank you.

Comment: I think you want this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368137/asynchronous-shell-commands

Comment: * Partially worked.  ScriptA now closes before ScriptB, but ScriptB doesn't close. ScriptB is as simple as echo a statement and exit. Any suggestions?

Comment: I would recommend making ScriptB a function that gets invoked from ScriptA.

Comment: That won't work for my needs.  Here is the issue: I need scriptA to do something, then after scriptA finishes, scriptB needs to execute separately. Is there a better way to accomplish this?