# How to run different dependable executable located in different directories?

Tags: linux, parallel-processing

I have a situation that I need to run different executables from different linux directories. The executables communicate through IP/TCP and the master-worker concept. Here I have a master directory which contains the master executable and different worker directories which contain the worker executables. Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
A- I have a master directory : /home/usr/scratch/master
B- I create an exact copy of master copy called it wrk1 
    :/home/usr/scratch/wrk1
C- cd to master directory and run the exe command: 
   ./exe arg1 /h :4004
where 4004 is a port number and arg1 and /h are just some arguments of exe
D- cd to wrk directory and run the following commands: 
   ./exe_wrk arg1 /h host:4004
```

Where host is the hostname of master directory

I wrote a simple sh script :

```
1- cd /home/usr/scratch/master
2- ./exe /h :4004
3- cd /home/usr/scratch/wrk1
4- ./exe /h host:4004
```

The problem is the program when I run the master exe, it pauses and waits for other worker exe to run. In another word, my script pauses at step 2 so it never get to step 3 and four to run the workers. I can do it manually by opening another terminal and run workers but is there any way that I can run it automatically?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asynchronous shell commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368137/asynchronous-shell-commands)

Comment: I tried the "myscript &" suggested there, but it still doing the same thing. It pauses at step two and never cd to wrk directory.

Comment: The accepted answer states *"Note that this is different from putting the `&` inside your script, which probably won't do what you want."* Did you look at the other answers with more options, or research using `&` in a script?

Comment: I think you want `.exe .... &` for each  mention of `.exe` **inside your script**. Good luck.